# Maximum file upload size in a single request for google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

For Google Drive on create file API I could see the Maximum file size: 5120 GB.
So my question here is, is this the maximum file size that can be uploaded in a "Single request"?. Or is it like we can have file of maximum size of 5120 GB but it has to be uploaded in chunks of some XXX size(lets say 2 GB max size for a chunk in a single request).

Comment: I don't think there is a max size have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your speed connection. It is possible to upload a 5 TB file. However, the possibility that it eventually fails to upload is pretty big. It is much wiser to create .rar compressed files and upload them.